# Can I Port a game written With SFML and c++ to android

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-platform, sfml

So , I created an Empty c++ Project In Visual Studio 2019 And Linked The Libraries ***Non-Staticly***
(That Means I Just The Placed The dll's in The Qutput Directory) And Then Closed VIsual Studio And Switched To VSCode And Now I Build The Project Using Devloper Cmd(Of Visual Studio Of Course) and MSBuild I Use SFML To Make The Project And Now Want To Port It Over To Android (Or IOS Or Both Anything Will Work)

Is There Any Way That This Can Happen ? Please Ask Me If You Want Any Other Information

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=Minimal%20and%20readable,correctly%20formatted%20on%20Stack%20Overflow.) before posting any question.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the `Mobile Development with C++` package in the Visual Studio Installer. Create a new C++ project using the template `Native-Activity Application (Android)`.

Trying to convert one project type to another is pointless and a waste of your time. However, your old source code can be included in the new project using the various right click actions.